# Converting ManagedObject to NSObject

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsmanagedobject, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to get the data from 'Employee' Entity which has empId, Name, deptId as attributes.

```
// Used to Populate data in table
Employee : NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property int empId;
@property int deptId;

@synthesize empId, name, deptId;
```

&

```
CDEmployee : NSManagedObject 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property int empId;
@property int deptId;
- (void)convertMyData:(Employee *)emp;

@dynamic empId, name, deptId;

- (void)convertMyData:(Employee *)emp
{
self.empId = emp.empId;
self.name = emp.name;
self.deptId = emp.deptId;
}


// My code to fetch & convert data retured from db to Employee class
-(NSArray *)getAllEmployees:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(empId > %@)",[NSNumber numberWithInt:-1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        NSFetchRequest* req = [self createRequest:context]; // Request is correct
        [req setPredicate:predicate];
        NSFetchedResultsController* fetchContr = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:req managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];

        NSError* error = nil;
        [fetchContr performFetch:&error];

        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [fetchContr fetchedObjects];
        NSMutableArray *result = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

        for(int i = 0; i < [fetchedObjects count]; i++)
        {
            CDEmployee *cdEmp = [[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:i] retain]; // just tried retaing

            if (cdEmp)
            {
                Employee *emp = [[Employee alloc] init];

                NSLog(@"Employee - %@", emp); // Shows tht is has object
                [cdEmp convertMyData:emp]; //-----> Crashing here

                [result addObject:emp];
                [emp release];
            }
        }
        [fetchContr release];
        return result;
}
```

I am fetching results from core data & I am getting correct results back, but when I convert my core data result back to `Employee(NSObject)` class i am getting **`[NSManagedObject convertMyData:]:` unrecognized selector sent to instance.**

I tried adding another method say `-(void)helloWorld` to `CDEmployee` class & tried `[cdEmp helloWorld];` but got the same crash.

Not getting why its causing the problem. I have method defined & implemented at proper place & its not even giving warning to me at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that converts `NSManagedObject` to `NSDictionary`.

`NSDictionary` is even more easier to handle and operate on the data than `NSObject`. Also refer this [Git Library](https://github.com/thatzprem/Utilities-Library/blob/master/ios-utilities/DataConverters/DataConverters.m) for other similar iOS utility class methods.

```
+(NSDictionary *)convertManagedObjectToDictionary:(NSManagedObject *)managedObject{

    if (!managedObject){
        NSLog(@"Managed object is nil");
        return nil;
    }
    else{

        unsigned int objectsCount;
        objc_property_t *objectProperties = class_copyPropertyList([managedObject class], &objectsCount);

        NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        for(int i = 0; i < objectsCount; i++) {
            objc_property_t property = objectProperties[i];
            NSString *name = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(property) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            id object = [managedObject valueForKey:name];
            [dictionary setObject:((object == nil) ? [NSNull null] : object) forKey:name];
        }
        free(objectProperties);
        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Comment: managedObject which I am passing is not null but, I m getting objectProperties as NULL & objectsCount as 0 is that mean my managedObject is empty. What shuld i do

Comment: @thatzprem You should correct it also in repository.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in different way & got resolved http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started

Answer (score -1):

First, you should really first think about what you want to accomplish from a non-technical perspective. What is it, actually?

Second, `NSManagedObject` is a subclass of `NSObject`, which means you already have a `NSObject`. Congratulations, you are done!

Also, in your code you call `fetchMyData` but did not show us where you define it or what the code looks like. Maybe a `NSManagedObject` *category* would be in order here? But still, this begs the question why you would want to do this. Even if you were to convert into a Foundation object, such as `NSDictionary` as suggested in the other answer, you would still have a problem with modelling relationships...

Finally, what SDK are you using? You can't be serious if you are still not using ARC.

Comment: `NSManagedObject` is always context dependent. It means for example if you have one context and try to pass managed objects through various threads - the app may fall down.